# iOS Check if Coming from Particular View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm working on an iPhone app where I move through push through several view controllers. On the last on I `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

I want to ask is there a way to detect that I just came from ViewController7 when i return to the ViewController1?

The reason being i'd like the `viewDidAppear` to behave in a certain way if it is.

Otherwise is it possible to rerun the ViewDidLoad? (I'm presuming its not).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your viewController1 conform to the [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007662) protocol and become the `UINavigationController`'s delegate. Then in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` check if the controller to be shown is viewController1, check your `UINavigationController`'s `visibleViewController` and set some variable in viewController1. Then in `viewDidAppear` you can animate appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the delegation design pattern to set a protocol method to send information back regarding what view controller you are in.